# printing common elements in a binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am new to c++ and i am trying to implement binary search tree data structure using c++.The following code is for printing the common elements in given two binary search trees.My approach to this problem is that i am creating two arrays of elements of binary search tree 1 and binary search tree 2, ie.. arr1[],arr2[].In the method **create_Array()** i am storing the values of both the binary trees in sorted order,so when i print values there it prints in sorted order,But when i try to print the values of arr1 & arr2 in method **printcommon()** 
it prints not in sorted order but in the order it is there in the tree.

sample input is:-

> 6
>
> 5 6 4 1 2 3
>
> 8
>
> 6 9 4 10 2 3 5 9

sample output is

> Tree 1=1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> Tree 2=2 3 4 5 6 9 10
>
> Common Nodes=2 3 4 5 6

actual output is:

> TREE 1=1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> TREE 2=2 3 4 5 6 9 10
>
> Common Nodes=

for more clarity the line which i have commented in method printcommon() prints arr1[0] as 5 but it should print 1,but in function create_Array() the commented line prints perfectly in sorted order,ie.. 1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,9,10. 
So if arr1[0] value is 1 in method create_Array(),how it became as 5 from arr1[0] = 1.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct BstNode
    {
        int data;
        BstNode *left;
        BstNode *right;
    };
    int n1, n2;
    BstNode* getNewNode(int element)
    {
        BstNode* newNode = new BstNode;
        newNode->data = element;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }
    BstNode* create_Tree(BstNode* root, int element)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            root = getNewNode(element);
        }
        else if (element < root->data)
        {
            root->left = create_Tree(root->left, element);
        }
        else if (element > root->data)
        {
            root->right = create_Tree(root->right, element);
        }
        return root;
    }
    void InOrder_Traversal(BstNode * root)
    {
        if (root == NULL) return;
        else
            InOrder_Traversal(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        InOrder_Traversal(root->right);
    }
    void create_Array(BstNode * root, int arr[], int k)
    {
        if (root == NULL) return;
        create_Array(root->left, arr, k);
        arr[k] = root->data;
        /*cout << arr[k] << endl;*             /*please focus on this line
                                                prints in sorted order*/
        k++;
        create_Array(root->right, arr, k);
    }
    void printCommon(BstNode *root1, BstNode *root2)
    {
        int *arr1 = new int[n1];
        int i = 0;
        create_Array(root1, arr1, i);
        int *arr2 = new int[n2];
        int j = 0;
        create_Array(root2, arr2, j);
        cout << "Common Nodes=";
        /*cout << arr1[0];*/  /* this dosent print in sorted order*/                           
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            {
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                {
                    cout << arr2[j] << " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        BstNode* root1 = NULL;
        BstNode* root2 = NULL;
        int n1, n2, ele;
        cin >> n1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        {
            cin >> ele;
            root1 = create_Tree(root1, ele);
        }
        cin >> n2;
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        {
            cin >> ele;
            root2 = create_Tree(root2, ele);
        }
        cout << "TREE 1=";
        InOrder_Traversal(root1);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "TREE 2=";
        InOrder_Traversal(root2);
        cout << endl;
        printCommon(root1, root2);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: input-6(n1)

5 6 4 1 2 3
8(n2)

6 9 4 10 2 3 5 9

Comment: after size(n1,n2) tree elements are given

Comment: i edited it and added sample o/p , i/p , actual o/p

Comment: @AyushMishra Well, what did you observe when stepping through your code line by line using the debugger? Would you mind adding those observations as well to your question plase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this covers all your problems but it's a bug that will make your code fail.

Here:

```
int n1, n2;  <<<<<<<< NOTICE
BstNode* getNewNode(int element)
```

you make **global** variables `n1` and `n2` that you want to use in some functions like `printCommon`

But here:

```
int main()
{
    BstNode* root1 = NULL;
    BstNode* root2 = NULL;
    int n1, n2, ele;    <<<<<<<<<<<<< NOTICE
    cin >> n1;
```

you make local variables with the same name and take the input into the **local** variables.

So when the function `printcommon` is called, it doesn't use the input values but uses the **global** variables that have the value zero.

You can see this by doing `cout << "n1 is " << n1 << endl;` inside the function and inside `main` (just after reading the input).

**EDIT**

The above didn't fix all the problems. Another problem is the `create_array` function where the index (aka `k`) is wrong, i.e. it doesn't write to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... but goes back to zero an overwrites previous elements.

A way to fix that problem is to use a pointer for the index. Something like:

```
void create_Array(BstNode * root, int arr[], int * k)
{
    if (root == NULL) return;
    create_Array(root->left, arr, k);
    arr[*k] = root->data;
    (*k)++;
    create_Array(root->right, arr, k);
}
```

and call it like

```
create_Array(root1, arr1, &i);
                          ^ notice
```

Comment: still the value of arr1[0] is 5 instead of 1 and in function create_Array() value of arr1[0] is 1.

Comment: @AyushMishra Which tells you that your `create_Array` is wrong. Tip: Add this `cout << "index " << k << " gets the value " << arr[k] << endl;` just after the line `arr[k] = root->data;` and you'll see the problem

Comment: is there any way to correct my itertion of  **k** ?

Comment: @AyushMishra Well, my guess is that you can work with a pointer instead. Like `void create_Array(BstNode * root, int arr[], int * k)` but I have not tested it.